# Can Storm replay a stream which emitted by a Bolt?

Tags: apache-storm

[image: Simple Storm Topology]

With storm's reliable spouts, it's possible to replay a tuple stream which is failed to process. As I understand it is only possible to replay a stream from a spout. Is it possible to replay a stream emitted from a Bolt, if that stream was failed to processed by the next bolt? i.e If "Bolt B" is unavailable due to some reason, does "Bolt A" capable of replay the "Stream 2" once "Bolt B" becomes available again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by Storm.

If Bolt B fails, a replay can only be done from the Spout. Let's assume Spout emits a tuple *t1* that is processed by Bolt A and results in an output tuple *t2*. If *t2* cannot be processed by Bolt B, the Spout can re-emit tuple *t1*, which is processed a second time by Bolt A resulting again in output tuple *t2*.

Of course, Bolt A must produce the same output tuple *t2* when processing *t1* a second time. Furthermore, the processing order is changed. The Spout can emit other tuples before re-emitting *t1*, ie, Bolt B might receive tuples in different order after failure (*t2* will most likely not be the first tuple when Bolt B is recovered).

Comment: Is it possible to achieve such behavior even with Trident?

Comment: Trindent uses the same mechanism, as it is basically just a high-level API that compiles down to regular spouts and bolts. Trident can even preserve the order an avoid duplicates in the output. You might want to read the documentation about transactional topologies to understand the background: https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Transactional-topologies.html